# My controller is -persistently- sending wrong params[:id] in Rails?!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I'm new to Ruby on Rails & to web programming.
In my application I have two models; Directorate which `has_many :users`, and User which `belongs_to :directorate`.
When creating a new user, I use `<%= f.collection_select(:directorate_id,Directorate.all, :id, :name) %>` in the new.html.erb form to assign the new user to specific directorate. However, I want to build a user-friendly interface for the dba that lists all directorates; and listing all users beside each directorate, with a link to assign any user to a specific directorate.

What I did is the following:

In Directorate model, I defined the following function:

```
   def assign_user!(user)
      user.update_attributes(directorate_id: @directorate)
   end
```

and in the directorates controller, I defined the following action:

```
 def assign_user
   @directorate = params[:directorate]
   assign_user! params[:user]
   redirect_to directorates_url
 end
```

Now, directorates/index.html.erb contains the following:

```
    <h1>Listing directorates</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Info</th>
  </tr>

<% @directorates.each do |directorate| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= directorate.name %></td>
    <td><%= directorate.info %></td>

    <td><%= link_to 'Show', directorate %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_directorate_path(directorate) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', directorate, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
    <%= @directorate = directorate%>
<%= render 'users_form' %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Directorate', new_directorate_path %>
```

and, -users_form.html.erb contains the following form (which is supposed to list all users beside each directorate, with a link to assign any user to a certain directorate):

```
    <h1>Listing Users</h1>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>User Name</th>
      </tr>

      <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>

        <td><%= user.username %></td>

        <td><%= link_to 'Assign to Current Directorate', {controller: 'directorates', action: 'assign_user', directorate: @directorate, user: user}, :method => :put %></td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>

<br />
```

Here is the problem, when listing directorates & click on the 'Assign to Current Directorate' I receive the following error:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/directorates/assign_user?directorate=4&user=5

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in DirectoratesController#update

Couldn't find Directorate with id=assign_user
Rails.root: /home/ehab/sites/IAMS

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/directorates_controller.rb:61:in `update'
Request

Parameters:

{"_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"L5tz3hv2IW0meE79qUq0/tjfGKwDlpC23hOeAWtmTvk=",
 "directorate"=>"4",
 "user"=>"5",
 "id"=>"assign_user"}
```

It's clear that the params is submitting "id"=>"assign_user" which I don't want, what i want is "id"=>"directorate.id" (4 in the above example). What shall I do to fix this issue?!

Comment: What's your routes.rb look like?

Comment: Originally, it was:
  
  get 'directorates/assign_user'
  resources :directorates
  resources :users

Then I modified it to:

  get 'directorates/assign_user'
  resources :directorates do
     resources :users
  end

But either solved the problem for me :(

Comment: I also tried to explicitly include ':method => :put' in the link_to and then removed it, but none solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all your routes should say that assign_user is a `member` method on a certain `directorate` object:

```
resources :directorates do
  member do
    put :assign_user
  end
end
```

second you say you define `assign_user!` in `Directorate` model and `assign_user` in `DirectoratesController` but both methods imply that they share same object state like instance variable `@directorate` which is not true

your controller method `assign_user` should look vaguely like

```
def assign_user
  @directorate = Directorate.find params[:id]
  @user        = User.find params[:user_id]

  @directorate.assign_user! @user
end
```

and model method should look like

```
def assign_user!(user)
  user.update_attributes(directorate_id: self.id)
end
```

and even that i would switch around to instead of telling `Directorate` to change user's attributes you would tell `User` to assign itself to whatever controller wants.

and the final bit is your link that assigns user to directorate:

```
link_to 'Assign to Current Directorate',
  assign_user_directorates_path(@directorate, :user_id => user)
```

0 lines of code above were tested for even syntactical correctness, DO NOT copy-paste, read and understand

Comment: Thanks Keymone. This actually worked out. As I said earlier, I'm totally new to web development & to ROR ... your comment regarding: resources :directorates do
  member do
    put :assign_user
  end
end saved my day :)